# Why we require SMTP Service to be installed while configuring IIS 5.1 or 6.0?

Tags: iis-6, iis, wcf

I am deploying WCF service and for that I have to configure IIS 5.1 or 6.0..

Why we require SMTP Service to be installed while configuring IIS 5.1 or 6.0?

Could we uncheck a SMTP Service Option while configuring IIS 5.1 or 6.0?

Answer (score 3):

SMTP is optional, so you can install it or not. this is use for sending mails from your server to other mailing servers.